# Two-Finger Right Click in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, regedit

I realize this question may not be appropriate for this Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find one that was for Windows or otherwise more relevant. If so, I apologize and would appreciate being redirected to the appropriate place. Also, I am a programmer and I'm trying to accomplish this to increase my productivity while programming on Windows.

**The Problem**
I have a Razer Blade 14 running Windows 8.1 which has a multi-touch trackpad. I would like to use two finger-tap to right click but the tutorials I've found online indicate I edit somewhere in RegEdit that doesn't exist in my own.

Does anyone have ideas on how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should go in Mouse settings and find the option.
On mine Synaptics pointer driver is installed which gives me an option of configuring multi touch input and bind it to right click.

Comment: Can you share where you navigate to to get there? I explored this and did find tap options but not two finger tap for right click.